# Is there a more efficient RegEx for solving Wordle?

Tags: regex, wordle-game

So I have a list of all 5 letter words in the English language that I can interrogate when I'm really stuck at Wordle. I found this an excellent exercise for brushing up on my Regular Expressions in BBEDIT, which is what I tell myself I'm doing.

The way wordle works, I can have three conditions.

1. A letter that is somewhere in the word (and must be present)
2. A letter that is not present in the word
3. A letter that is correct in presence and position

Condition 3 is easy. If my start word "crone" has the n in the right place, my pattern is

```
...n.
```

And I can add condition 2 fairly easily with

```
^(?!.*[croe])...n.
```

If my next guess is "burns" I'll know there's an "s"

```
^(?!.*[croebur])^(?=.*s)...n.
```

And that it's not in the last position:

```
^(?!.*[croebur])^(?=.*s)...n[^s]
```

If my next (very poor) guess is 'stone' I'll know there's a 't'.

```
^(?!.*[croebur])^(?=.*s)^(?=.*t)sa.n.
```

So that's a workable formula.

But if my next guess were "wimpy" I'd know there was an 'i' in the answer, but I have to add an additional `^(?=.*i)` which just feels inefficient. I tried grouping the letters that must be in the word by using a bracket set, `^(?=.*[ist])` but of course that will match targets that contain any one of those characters rather than all.

Is there a more efficient way to express the phrase "the word must contain all of the following letters to match" than a series of "start at the beginning, scan for occurence of this single character until the end" phrases?

Comment: A word in brackets can find multiple letters with the `/g` flag. Ex. `/[ghost]/g` will find`g`, `o`, and `t` of `goat`.

Comment: No. Your approach is fine and easy to programmatically produce. "Efficiency" of execution doesn't come into it with an input of only 5 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enter a word into Wordle, it displays all the matched characters in your word. It also shows the characters which exist in the word but not in the correct order.

Considering these requirements, I think you should create different rules for each letter's place. This way, your regex pattern keeps simple, and you get the search results quickly. Let me give an example:

1. Input word: `crone`
   Matched Characters: `...n.`
   Characters in the wrong place: -
   Next regex search pattern: `^[^crone][^crone][^crone]n[^crone]$`
2. Input word: `burns`
   Matched Characters: `...n.`
   Characters in the wrong place: `s`
   Next regex search pattern: `^(?=\S*[s]\S*)[^bucrone][^bucrone][^bucrone]n[^bucrones]$` (Be careful, there is an "s" character in the last parenthesis because we know its place isn't there.)
3. Input word: `stone`
   Matched Characters: `s..n.`
   Characters in the wrong place: `t`
   Next regex search pattern: `^(?=\S*[t]\S*)s[^tsbucrone][^sbucrone]n[^sbucrones]$` (Be careful, there is a "t" character in the first parenthesis because we know its place isn't there.)

- `^` => Start of the line
- `[^abc]` => Any character except "a" and "b" and "c"
- `(?=\S*[t]\S*)`=> There must be a "t" character in the given string
- `(?=\S*[t]\S*)(?=\S*[u]\S*)`=> There must be "t" and "u" characters in the given string
- `$` => End of the line

When we look at performance tests of the regex patterns with a seven-word sample, my regex pattern found the result in 130 steps, whereas your pattern in 175 steps. The performance difference will increase as the word-list increase. You can review it from the following links:

- Suggested pattern: https://regex101.com/r/mvHL3J/1
- Your pattern: https://regex101.com/r/Nn8EwL/1

Note: You need to click the "Regex Debugger" link in the left sidebar to see the steps.

Note 2: I updated my response to fix the bug in the following comment.

Comment: That IS better. And thanks for the tip on the debugger. Very handy. If nobody bests this I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Just tried this, and realized it is more efficient in the test case, but it fails to eliminate impossible answers. If you add the words sling and spank to the target list and use your final iteration of the Regex, they're hits, despite the fact we know that a "t" must occur in the correct answer. https://regex101.com/r/MrcAhR/1

Comment: @brianfit You are right. We can overcome its by adding `(?=\S*[t]\S*)` prefix. It means there must be a "t" character in the word. You can look sample here https://regex101.com/r/mvHL3J/1 . If you know multiple characters exist in the word, then you can use the `(?=\S*[t]\S*)(?=\S*[u]\S*)` prefix for "u" and "t" characters.

Comment: Yep, that works. And the debugger reports it's more efficient than mine.